# how to toggle maya icons with python in maya

Tags: python, icons, maya

I'm currently trying to have my iconTextButton change its given icon to a different image once clicked. Is this possible at all.

```
def defaultButtonPush(*args):
print 'Button 1 was pushed.'

cmds.window( width=150 )
cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
cmds.iconTextButton(style='iconAndTextHorizontal', image1= 'cube.png',image2= 'sphere.png', label='Button 1', command=defaultButtonPush )

cmds.showWindow()
```

many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close, you can define a reference string to most elements created in Maya. If you notice, in the command reference for the [iconTextButton](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/CommandsPython/index.html), image1 is editable, so we can change this with the command you had linked to your iconButton.

This is the main code I added, please note the 'iconButton' name, which I have also added to the iconTextButton when you first created it!

`cmds.iconTextButton('iconButton', edit=True, image1='newimage.jpg')`

So here's everything put together:

```
def defaultButtonPush(*args):
    cmds.iconTextButton('iconButton', edit=True, image1='newimage.jpg')

cmds.window( width=150 )
cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
cmds.iconTextButton('iconButton', style='iconAndTextHorizontal', image1= 'cube.png',image2= 'sphere.png', label='Button 1', command=defaultButtonPush )

cmds.showWindow()
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work without any problems!